# JQuery radio value always return 0

Tags: html, jquery, .net

I'm trying to take radio value for update database.I can see the id from consolelog but when it goes to controller it returns 0 always. here is my code. I tried everything in the google but didn't help.

```
var loadCustomersRate = function () {
    App.loading.start('#pageBody');
    App.post('/RateChange/CustomerRates?customerId=' + customerId, {}, function (result) {
        if (result.Code == "OK") {
            $.each(result.Data, function (key, value) {
                $('#customerRatesList')
                    .append($("<input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='radio'>  <label></label><br>")
                        .attr("value", value.Id)
                        .text(value.RateName));
            });
            $('input').change(function () {
                currentRateId = $(this).val();
                console.log(currentRateId);
            });
        }
            else {
                App.showMessage('error', 'İşlem Başarısız. (' + result.Message + ')', 'Hata');
            }
            App.loading.end('#pageBody');
        }, false);
}
```

I'm trying to use this at in this block

```
var updateSingleRate = function () {
    $('#checkboxBtn').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('Rate will change.');
            $('#saveBtn').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'UpdateSingleRate',
                    data: { customerId: customerId, selectedRate: selectedRateId, currentRate: currentRateId },
                    success: function (response) { App.showMessage('OK') },
                    error: function (response) { App.showMessage('Danger') }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and the html code

```
<div id="customerRates">
                <label class="control-label">CurrentRates</label><br /><br />
                <ol id="customerRatesList"></ol>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to change this:

```
$('#customerRatesList')
                    .append($("<input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='radio'>  <label></label><br>")
                        .attr("value", value.Id)
                        .text(value.RateName));
```

To this:

```
$('#customerRatesList')
                    .append("<input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='radio'>  <label></label><br>")
                        .attr("value", value.Id)
                        .text(value.RateName);
```

What you have attempts to append a jQuery object as opposed to HTML as I believe you intended.

**EDIT**:
I modified your code to run within a snippet (see below). There were several issues that I have attempted to resolve.

**What I changed**

- I added `<li></li>` tags to your append of the `<ul>` tag to make it semantically correct. I also changed from `<ol>` to `<ul>` for sake of clarity. I think this is what you want anyway.
- The append now uses a template literal to make it "cleaner" to directly insert the **id** and **rateName** values.
- I commented the **.attr()** and **.text()** methods which were incorrectly attached to the `<ul>` tag. The bullet-point above replaces this. See the comments within the snippet.
- I changed the **$('input').change** function from `currentRateId = $(this).val();` to `currentRateId = $(this).attr('id');`. Using **.val()** always returned "on" while **.attr('id')** returns the id value which is what I think you were going for.

Please incorporate these changes into your code and see if that takes care of your issue.

```js
// simulated ajax response (array of objects)
let result = {};
result.Code = "OK";
result.Data = [{
    id: 1,
    rateName: "Rate A"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    rateName: "Rate B"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    rateName: "Rate C"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    rateName: "Rate D"
  }
];
// end - simulated ajax response

if (result.Code == "OK") {
  $.each(result.Data, function(key, value) {
    $('#customerRatesList')
      .append(`<li><input type='radio' class='radioBtnClass' name='radio' id='${value.id}'>${value.rateName}</li>`)
    //.attr("value", value.Id) <--- This was trying to change the "value" attribute of the <ul>. <ul> has no "value" attribute.
    //.text(value.RateName); <--- This was trying to change the "text" attribute of the <ul>. <ul> has no "text" attribute.
  });
  $('input').change(function() {
    currentRateId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("currentRateId", currentRateId);
  });
} else {
  console.log("failed");
  //App.showMessage('error', 'İşlem Başarısız. (' + result.Message + ')', 'Hata');
}
//App.loading.end('#pageBody');
//}, false);
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="customerRates">
  <label class="control-label">CurrentRates</label><br /><br />
  <ul id="customerRatesList"></ul>
</div>
```